# Safari incorporating URL # fragment into its browser caching

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, safari, fragment

I'm working on a solution to speed our website up.  I'm having the client first ajax load the expected next page of the application:

```
$.ajax({url: '/some/real/path', ...});
```

The server responds to this and includes in the header:

```
Cache-Control => 'max-age=20'
```

which marks the response as being cachable.

The clientside application then waits to see if its prediction was correct, and upon finding that it was, transitions the browser to that same page, but adds a few bits of information into the URL as a # fragment, where this info is available to us only when the user has actually committed their action (i.e. not predictable):

```
location.href = '/some/real/path#additionalInfoInFragement';
```

When the browser transition to the page the additional info in the fragment is picked up by that page's javascript and worked to achieve some effect there.

For all browser, including Safari, the response to the starting ajax request IS properly inserted into the browser cache.

And then, for all browsers except Safari, the browser pulls that content out of the cache when we effect the location.href transition to that page.  This avoids the server hit and is the basis for our speed-up.

Safari though is not using the cache to re-serve the content.  It seems to get tripped up by the '#additionalInfoInFragment' part of the transition.  It is including the fragment in its construction of the cache key it uses to check for existing cached content.  Here are the entries from Safari's cache.db file, which I dumped via sqlite:

```
* ajax request: INSERT INTO "cfurl_cache_response" VALUES(3260,0,-1982644086,0,'http://localhost:8080/TomcatScratchPad/EmptyPage','2012-05-14 07:01:10');

* location.href transition: INSERT INTO "cfurl_cache_response" VALUES(3276,0,-230554366,0,'http://localhost:8080/TomcatScratchPad/EmptyPage#wtf','2012-05-14 07:01:20');
```

Also notable is the fact that Chrome is behaving correctly, even though both share a tremendous amount of WebKit code.

I would really appreciate any ideas the community has.  Thanks!

Comment: Can I just say: Wow, you've really looked into this deeply. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

I see only a couple of options:

1. File a bug report with Apple and don't worry about it. :-) Your caching stuff will still work for other browsers. Overall, Safari has a [*very* small market share](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), although of course if your site is targeted at (say) iPad or iPhone users, that rather changes the nature of the stats for your specific site. :-) (You presumably know from your logs how big your Safari audience is.)

   Sub-category: If Safari is a big part of your target market and this really bothers you, see if it's a bug in any of the open source parts of it and, if so, offer a patch.
2. Don't use the fragment identifier to pass the information, use something else (a cookie perhaps) instead.